# How do I factor $670726081$ if I have the informations that $33335^2\equiv670705093^2 \pmod{670726081}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How do I factor $670726081$ if I have the informations that $33335^2\equiv670705093^2 \pmod{670726081}$?

I know that $\gcd(33335+670705093,670726081)$ is a nontrivial factor of $670726081$

Comment: If you know that `gcd(...)` is a nontrivial factor, then what are you asking?

Comment: Hint:  The euclidean algorithm lets you compute $\gcd (a,b)$ quite efficiently, even if the numbers are large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the intended trick is that the second number is very close to the bigger number, and $670726081 - 670705093 = 20988.$

As a result, 
$$ 33335^2 \equiv  20988^2 \pmod {670726081}  $$

So
$$ 33335^2 -  20988^2 = 670726081 \; k  $$ and
$$ 54323 \cdot 12347 = 670726081 \; k  $$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $670705093=670726081-20988$, so
\begin{align*}
33335^2&\equiv 670705093^2\mod(670726081)\\
       &\equiv 20988^2\mod(670726081),
\end{align*}
which follows that
\begin{align*}
33335^2-20988^2&\equiv 0\mod(670726081).
\end{align*}
Now by writing
$$33335^2-20988^2=(33335+20988)(33335-20988)=54323\cdot12347,$$
we see that $54323\cdot12347=670726081k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and it is not difficult to see that $k=1$.